# SQL SubQueries Execution

Tags: sql

**"Find the departments that have the highest average salary."**

```
select dept_name
from instructor
group by dept_name
having avg (salary) >= all (select avg (salary)
                            from instructor
                            group by dept_name)
```

Based on the above nested subquery, I am a little confused how it is executed. Can someone confirm if my interpretation is correct?

First the second line `from instructor` will run and from that relation the tuples will be grouped by `dept_name`. Then on that newly formed relation which is grouped by `dept_name`, you will check the average salary for each group and compare value to all the other average salaries from a new instructor relation that was formed in the sub query. Is this correct? The subquery will form a new relation so you will actually have two separate relation that are operated on?

```
(select avg (salary)
from instructor
group by dept_name)
```

In the above subquery, I originally thought whichever attributes are not aggregated in the group by clause **HAVE** to appear in the select clause. But in this case why isn't `dept_name` present in the select clause in the subquery?

Comment: Just changed it to text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is running in two segments. The first is your nested query (which is actually executed as a [Left Anti Semi join](http://sqlity.net/en/1360/a-join-a-day-the-left-anti-semi-join/)). This returns the average salaries for each of your dept_name.

```
--Nested Query Returns all dept_name average salaries
select avg (salary)
from #instructor
group by dept_name
```

This is then compared to your average salaries pulled in your main select statement using the "[All](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_all.php)" operator. This is the equivalent of comparing versus the greatest average salary from all of the departments. Think of it like the following:

```
Main Select       Nested Comparison
Math 200     >=   Max({Math 200, Bio 250, English 100})
Bio 250      >=   Max({Math 200, Bio 250, English 100})
English 100  >=   Max({Math 200, Bio 250, English 100})
```

So in the case of your query it will always only return Departments that "have" an average salary "equal to or greater" than the highest average salary. Below is an easy version to play with and help in your understanding.

```
Drop Table #instructor 
Create Table #instructor (dept_name nvarchar(200), salary money)
Insert Into #instructor 
Select 'Math', 200
Union Select 'English', 150
Union Select 'Biology', 275
Union Select 'Computer Science', 300

select dept_name
from #instructor
group by dept_name
having avg (salary) >= all(select avg (salary)
                            from #instructor
                            group by dept_name)
```

You will notice that in the above example the only department that shows up  is Computer Science. But if you change Biology to 300 as well, then both Biology and Computer Science will show up.

Comment: Ohh now this makes compete sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: No Problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

Columns in the `group by` do *not* have to appear in the `select`.  This is a case where that is not possible, because the query needs to return only one column.

The result of this query:

```
select avg(salary)
from instructor
group by dept_name
```

is simply a list of the average salaries in each department.  As a query by itself, this would be more useful if you also had the department name.  But that is unneeded in this case.

Comment: So will the subquery return a relation of the average salaries in each department?

Comment: The subquery returns a list of values, which the `ALL` operator can operate on.

Comment: Oh ok. Can you please explain what you mean by "with the `ALL` operators can operate on"